# HTML force div to appear bottom of the div

Tags: html, css

I have this http://jsbin.com/AKUtEYu/1/edit.

Here, I want to show an image inside the div1 and below this div1, i also want to show a submit button inside the div2. The problem I have here is that the second div appears underneath of the first div.

P.S 1: I need to use `position:absolute` in the first div. I know if i remove it, the problem seems to be fixed, but i am looking for a way with it.

P.S 2: I used solid borders to see what is going on.

Comment: Please include the relevant code here instead of linking to an external site. If the external site changes or goes away, this question then loses context and becomes useless.

Comment: people have no clue what you mean. very unclear.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/AKUtEYu/6/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated slightly ahead of me, move your submit button inside the `#container` parent block:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="http://31.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m50exyThDb1r4kc3co1_500.jpg" />

    <div id="footerSubmit">
        <input type="submit" alt="Submit" id="SubmitSelections" name="Submit">
    </div>
</div>
```

Otherwise, you will have to set a height on `#container` and absolute or relative position on the `#footerSubmit`, which is a lot more work...

Comment: But, if i remove position:absolute, i get what I want. How can I get the same effect by keeping position:absolute. Do you think it is possible?

Comment: you mentioned about javascript solution, for that case i can also use it.

Comment: Absolute positioned elements are taken out of the document flow. In your example, this means that `#container` is out of the regular document layout, which means it does not know that `#footerSubmit` exits.  Likewise, `#footerSubmit` is not aware of `#container`.  As a result, `#footerSubmit` is positioned at the top of the page since it is the first in-flow element.  There are only two ways of keeping the footer below the image, wrap them both in the same parent container (as I showed) or specify a height for the `#container` and then use relative or absolute position on `#footerSubmit`.

Comment: is there a way to detect height of the #conainer and then assign it dynamically?

Comment: Yes, you can use JavaScript or jQuery to get the height of `#container` and then use that value to position `#footerSubmit`.

Comment: I am guessing that you are not able to modify the HTML, are you working off some CMS or template system?

Answer (score 0):

What if you put the second `div` inside the first? After all, the `div`s are just containers - the important thing is for the button to be placed under the picture.

Comment: @CoKoder Are you prepared to specify a height value for the image container?  Alternatively, do you want a JavaScript solution?

Comment: @MarcAudet, no i am not prepared to specify a height value for the image container. i wanna solve it with css.

Comment: If you 'wanna solve it' with CSS, then use absolute or relative positioning on `#footerSubmit` ...

Answer (score 0):

If you know height of your absolutde element/div then you can use it's height to position your relative element. for example change your div2 css as

```
#footerSubmit{
        position:relative;
        top:350px;
        float:right;
        border: 10px solid;
        color:red;

    }
```

Otherwise put your div2 inside div1 and position it as `bottom:0;` and `float:right;`